# Proof check: Baby Rudin 7.25

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am mostly concerned with part **(e)** since my version disagrees with the key that I checked my work against (I think the key's solution to this part is wrong). As I understand it, the functions $f_n$ are defined to be increasingly finer pieces of linear functions. Also, I was thinking about writing part **(f)** more rigorously which is why I wrote $N_1$ and $N_2$ but then I got lazy.

> **25.**<sup>[(source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taQIo.png)</sup> Suppose $\phi$ is a continuous bounded real function in the strip defined by $0\leq x\leq 1$, $-\infty<y<\infty$. Prove that the initial-value problem
>
> $$ y' = \phi(x, y), \qquad y(0) = c$$
>
> has a solution. (Note that the hypothesis of the existence theorem are less stringent than those of the corresponding uniqueness theorem; see Exercise 27, Chap. 5.)
>
> *Hint:* Fix $n$ For $i = 0, \cdots, n$, put $x_i  = i/n$. Let $f_n$ be a continuous function on $[0, 1]$ such that $f_n(0) = c$,
>
> $$ f'_n(t) = \phi(x_i, f_n(x_i)) \qquad \text{if } x_i < t < x_{i+1}$$
>
> and put
>
> $$ \Delta_n(t) = f_n'(t) - \phi(t, f_n(t)), $$
>
> except at the points $x_i$, where $\Delta_n(t) = 0$. Then
>
> $$ f_n(x) = c + \int_{0}^{x} [\phi(t, f_n(t)) + \Delta_n(t)] \, \mathrm{d}t $$
>
> Choose $M < \infty$ so that $|\phi|\leq M$. Verify the following assertions.
>
> (a) $|f_n'| \leq M$, $|\Delta_n| \leq 2M$, $\Delta \in \mathscr{R}$, and $|f_n| \leq |c| + M = M_1$, say, on $[0, 1]$, for all $n$.
>
> (b) $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous on $[0, 1]$, since $|f_n'| \leq M$.
>
> (c) Some $\{f_{n_k}\}$ converges to some $f$, uniformly on $[0, 1]$.
>
> (d) Since $\phi$ is uniformly continuous on the rectangle $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $|y| \leq M_1$,
>
> $$ \phi(t, f_{n_k}(t)) \to \phi(t, f(t)) $$
>
> uniformly on $[0, 1]$.
>
> (e) $\Delta_n(t) \to 0$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$, since
>
> $$ \Delta_n(t) = \phi(x_i, f_n(x_i)) - \phi(t, f_n(t)) $$
>
> in $(x_i, x_{i+1})$.
>
> (f) Hence
>
> $$ f(x) = c + \int_{0}^{x} \phi(t, f(t)) \, \mathrm{d}t $$
>
> This $f$ is a solution of the given problem.

**(a)**  Since $\phi$ is bounded there is $0<M<\infty$ (greater than $0$ to avoid issues with dividing by $M$) so that $|\phi|\leq M$. Since $f_n'(t)=\phi\left(x_i,f_n(x_i)\right)$ and $\Delta_n(t)=f_n'(t)-\phi\left(t,f_n\left(t\right)\right)$ in $(x_i, x_{i+1})$, we clearly have
\begin{equation*}
|f_n'|\leq M 
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
|\Delta_n(t)|=|f_n'(t)-\phi\left(t,f_n\left(t\right)\right)|\leq |f_n'|+ |\phi| \leq 2M. 
\end{equation*}
Since $f_n'$ $(n=1,2,\ldots)$ is bounded and has at most $n$ points of discontinuity, we know that it is Riemann integrable (Theorem $6.10$). And so we have
\begin{align*} |f_n(x)| & \leq |c|+\int_0^x |f_n'(t)|dt \\& \leq |c|+\int_0^x M dt \\& \leq |c|+M=M_1.
\end{align*}

**(b)** If $x,y \in [0,1]$, then we have
\begin{align*} |f_n(y)-f_n(x)| & \leq \left| \int_x^y f_n'(t)dt \right| \\& \leq M|y-x|.
\end{align*}
So $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous, since every function in the sequence is $M$-Lipschitz (given $\varepsilon>0$ just use $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{M}$).

**(c)** We now combine the preceding parts to conclude by the Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem that there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k} \}$ that converges uniformly to some function $f$ on $[0,1]$.

**(d)** Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $\phi$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]\times[-M_1, M_1]$, there is $\delta>0$ so that
\begin{equation*}
    \left|\phi(t,u) - \phi(t,v)\right|<\varepsilon \text{ whenever } |u-v|<\delta.
\end{equation*}
From part **(c)** there is a positive integer $N_1$ so that 
\begin{equation*}
    \left|f_{n_k}(t) - f(t)\right| < \delta \text{ whenever } n_k \geq N_1.
\end{equation*}
So we have
\begin{equation*}
    \left|\phi\left(t, f_{n_k}(t)\right) - \phi \left(t,f(t)\right)\right| <\varepsilon \text{ whenever } n_k \geq N_1.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, $\phi\left(t, f_{n_k}(t)\right) \to \phi \left(t,f(t)\right)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

**(e)** Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $\phi$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]\times[-M_1, M_1]$, there is $\delta>0$ so that
\begin{equation*}
    \left|\phi(s,u) - \phi(t,v)\right|<\varepsilon \text{ whenever } \sqrt{(s-t)^2+(u-v)^2}<\delta.
\end{equation*}
Since $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $[0,1]$, there is $\delta_1>0$ so that
\begin{equation*}
    \left|f_n(s) - f_n(t)\right|<\sqrt{\frac{1}2}\delta \text{ whenever } |s-t|<\delta_1 \text{ and } n \in \mathbb N.
\end{equation*}
Choose $\delta'=\min\left\{ \sqrt{\frac{1}2}\delta, \delta_1 \right\}$. We know there is a positive integer $N_2$ so that $|x_{i(n)}-x_{i(n)+1}|<\delta'$.
So we have
\begin{equation*}
    \left|\phi\left(x_{i(n)}, f_n (x_{i(n)}) \right) - \phi \left(t,f_n(t)\right)\right| < \varepsilon \text{ whenever } n \geq N_2 \text{ and } t \in \left[x_{i(n)}, x_{i(n)+1}\right].
\end{equation*}
Therefore, $\Delta_n(t)=\phi\left(x_{i(n)}, f_n (x_{i(n)})\right)-\phi\left(t,f_n\left(t\right)\right) \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

**(f)** We now combine the preceding parts to conclude by Theorem $7.16$ that 
\begin{equation*}f(x)=c+\int_0^x \phi(t,f(t)) dt.\end{equation*}
Furthermore, $f(0)=c$ and $f'(x)=\phi\left(x,f(x)\right)$. Therefore, $f$ is a solution of the given problem.

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me (modulo Theorem 7.16 which I do not know what it is, although I suspect that it is about uniform convergence applied to convergence of Riemann integral).

Comment: Indeed it is! Theorem 7.16 (Baby Rudin): Suppose $g_n$ are Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, for $n=1,2,\ldots$, and suppose $g_n \to g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. Then $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and $\int_a^b g(t)dt = \int_a^b g_n(t) dt$.

Comment: Just a doubt, the found f in c) is not necessarily the limit of f_n, right? Maybe f should have been called g for example for better understanding.