# Show uniform convergence given a uniformly converging subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $\phi: [0,1 ] \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and continuous function. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $F_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy that for $t \in [0,1]$,  $F_n(0)=1/n$ and $F'_n(t)= \phi(t, F_n(t))$.

Show that there exists a $F$ such that $F(0)=0$ and $F'(t)=\phi(t, F(t))$.

First using Arzela-Ascoli, I showed that there exists a subsequence $(F_{n_k})_n$ such that it converges uniformly to a limit $F$.

Clearly, we have $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(0)=0$. Now we just have to show that $F'(t)= \phi(t, F(t))$.

Using triangle inequality, we have $|F(t)-F_n(t)| \leq |F(t)-F_{n_k}(t)| + |F_{n_k} -F_n(t)| < \epsilon +|F_{n_k} -F_n(t)| $, where the $\epsilon$ came from the subsequence $(F_{n_k})_n$  converging uniformly to a limit $F$.

Now we just have to show that $|F_{n_k} -F_n(t)| < \epsilon $. I thought of showing that $(F_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence so that since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, we will know that $(F_n)_n$ is converge.

But I'm stuck on finding a constant to prove that it's a Cauchy sequence.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: See my solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330448/proof-check-baby-rudin-7-25

Comment: I see nothing in the problem that requires you to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} F_n = F$. It simply asks you to show that some function $F$ exists with $F(0) = 0$ and $F'(t) = \phi(t,F(t))$. Since you've showed that there is a subsequence $F_{n_k}$ that converges to $F$, you are free to work just with that subsequence and pretend that the $F_n$ not in that subsequence do not even exist.